# Deleting arrays inside two-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods

I have this program that is supposed to make operations on 2 arrays and one of them is a two-dimensional array.
the method (removeStudent) that I created to remove a student's name plus his marks is not working.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Project {
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // The arrays are located outside the main method because the other methods are non=static methods
    String[] names= {"Nadim", "Sarah","Alfred","Nadim","Abed"};
    double[][] marks= {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {90, 45, 67, 23, 36},
            {80, 88, 50, 50, 50},
            {81, 85, 88, 91, 90}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project Class = new Project();
        String operation;
        String name;

        // This method prints the available operation to the user to know what
        Class.availableOperations();

        // This main switch statement controls all the methods ,and it is looped until the user inputs "quit" into the program
        do{
            System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the operation to begin: ");

            // This scanner decides what method the user will be using
            operation = scan.nextLine();

            switch (operation) {
                case "add" -> {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of the student: ");
                    name = scan.nextLine();
                    Class.addStudent(name);
                    Class.addMarks();
                }
                case "remove" -> {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of the student: ");
                    name = scan.nextLine();
                    Class.removeStudent(name);
                }
                case "print gpa" -> {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of the student: ");
                    name = scan.nextLine();
                    Class.findGpa(name);
                }
                case "print grades" -> {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of the student: ");
                    name = scan.nextLine();
                    Class.printStudentGrades(name);
                }
                case "find student by gpa" -> {
                    System.out.print("Enter the the GPA of the student: ");
                    double gpa = scan.nextDouble();
                    Class.findStudentByGpa(gpa);
                }
                case "lowest gpa" -> Class.lowestGpa();
                case "highest gpa" -> Class.highestGpa();
                case "print average" -> Class.findAverage();
                case "print all students grades" -> Class.printAllStudentsGrades();
                case "quit" -> System.out.println("Operation Done.");
                default -> System.out.println("This is not a valid operation.");
            }
        }while (!Objects.equals(operation, "quit"));
    }

    public void availableOperations() {
        System.out.println("""
                    Available Operations:\s
                    (add) To add a new student\s
                    (remove) To remove a Student\s
                    (print gpa) To get a student GPA\s
                    (print grades) To print the grades of a student\s
                    (print average) To get the average GPA of the class\s
                    (lowest gpa) To get the student with lowest GPA\s
                    (highest gpa) To get the student with highest GPA\s
                    (find student by gpa) To get the students who got a certain GPA\s
                    (print all students grades) To get the grades of every student\s
                    (quit) To Exit
                    """);
    }
    public void addStudent(String nameAdd) {
        // This array will hold the values of the original array plus the new one that the user inputs
        String[] moreNames= new String[names.length + 1];

        // This loop copies the values of the original array to the new one
        for (int i=0; i <names.length; i++) {
            moreNames[i] = names[i];
        }

        // This line of code add the new value inputted by the user
        moreNames[moreNames.length -1] = nameAdd;

        // Assigning the new array to the original one so the last results will be saved
        names= moreNames;
    }
    public void addMarks() {
        // Create a new 2D array with one more row than the original array to hold the original values plus the new ones
        double[][] newMarks = new double[marks.length + 1][marks[0].length];

        // Copy the values from the original array to the new array
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
            newMarks[i] = marks[i];
        }

        // Looping the scanner to input the grades of the newly added student
        for (int i = 0; i < marks[0].length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter mark " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            newMarks[newMarks.length - 1][i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        // Assigning the new array to the original one to save the last results
        marks = newMarks;
    }
    public void removeStudent(String nameToRemove) {
        int namesLength = 0;

        // This loop iterates through the array and saves how much names match the one the user wants to remove
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (Objects.equals(nameToRemove, names[i])) {
                namesLength++;
            }
        }

        if (namesLength > 0) {

            // Creating a new array to hold the original values minus the ones the user wants to delete
            String[] newNames = new String[names.length - namesLength];

            int namesIndexLess = 0;

            // Copying the values from the original array to the new one except the ones the user wants to delete
            for (String name : names) {
                if (!Objects.equals(name, nameToRemove)) {
                    newNames[namesIndexLess] = name;
                    namesIndexLess++;
                }
            }

            // Assigning the new array to the original one to save the last results
            names = newNames;

            // Creating a new array to hold the original values minus the ones the user wants to delete
            double[][] newMarks = new double[marks.length - namesLength][marks[0].length];

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                if (!Objects.equals(names[i], nameToRemove)) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < marks[i].length; y++) {
                        newMarks[count][y] = marks[i][y];
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }

            //making the main marks array equal to the new one to save the last results
            marks = newMarks;

            for (int i=0; i < marks.length; i++) {
                for (int p=0; p < marks[i].length; p++) {
                    System.out.println(marks[i][p]);
                }
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry no student with this name exists in our database");
        }
    }
    public void printStudentGrades(String studentName) {
        int StudentNumber =1;
        for (int i =0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (Objects.equals(studentName, names[i])) {
                System.out.println("\n");
                for (int v =0; v <marks.length; v++) {
                    if (i == v) {
                        System.out.println("Student number " + StudentNumber++ + ":");
                        for (int p =0; p <marks[v].length; p++) {
                            System.out.print(marks[v][p] + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void printAllStudentsGrades() {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + Arrays.toString(marks[i]));
        }
    }
    public void findStudentByGpa(double gpa) {
        int y = -1;
        int sum;

        //in the line below I made a new array to hold the values that the loop will create from teh old array
        double[] newMarks= new double[marks.length];

        //the loop will make new values to then put in a new array that hold 5 summations of the old secondary arrays
        for (int i= 0; i <marks.length; i++) {
            y++;
            sum = 0;
            for (int j =0; j<marks[i].length; j++) {
                sum += marks[i][j];
            }
            double initialGpa = sum/5;
            newMarks[y] = initialGpa;
        }

        for (int i =0; i < newMarks.length; i++) {
            if (gpa == newMarks[i]) {
                System.out.println(names[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    public void findGpa(String nameSum) {
        int numberOfStudents =0;
        double sum;
        //this loop is pretty simple, and I've used it many times, and it basically sums the marks of the chosen student to then get divided by the length of the array to give us the gpa
        for (int g= 0; g <names.length; g++) {
            sum =0;
            if (Objects.equals(nameSum, names[g])) {
                for (int j =0; j< marks[g].length; j++) {
                    sum += marks[g][j];
                }
                double avg = (sum/5);
                System.out.println("The average of student "+ ++numberOfStudents + " is "+ avg);
            }
        }
    }
    public void findAverage() {
        int y = -1;
        int sum;

        //in the line below I made a new array to hold the values that the loop will create from teh old array
        double[] newMarks= new double[marks.length];

        //the loop will make new values to then put in a new array that hold 5 summations of the old secondary arrays
        for (int i= 0; i <marks.length; i++) {
            y++;
            sum = 0;
            for (int j =0; j<marks[i].length; j++) {
                sum += marks[i][j];
            }
            double gpa = sum/5;
            newMarks[y] = gpa;
        }

        double sum2=0;
        for (int i =0; i< newMarks.length; i++) {
            sum2 += newMarks[i];
        }

        double avg = sum2/ newMarks.length;
        System.out.println("The Average GPA of the class is " + avg);
    }
    public void lowestGpa() {
        int y = -1;
        int sum;

        //in the line below I made a new array to hold the values that the loop will create from teh old array
        int[] newMarks= new int[marks.length];

        //the loop will make new values to then put in a new array that hold 5 summations of the old secondary arrays
        for (int i= 0; i <marks.length; i++) {
            y++;
            sum = 0;
            for (int j =0; j<marks[i].length; j++) {
                sum += marks[i][j];
            }
            newMarks[y] = sum;
        }

        int newSum =newMarks[0];
        int num=0;

        //in this loop I can find the lowest gpa of the students
        for (int z=0; z< newMarks.length; z++) {
            if (newMarks[z] < newSum) {
                newSum = newMarks[z];
                num = z;
            }
        }
        //The lowestStudent variable stores name of the student who got the gpa
        String lowestStudent = names[num];
        double newGpa =newSum/5;
        System.out.println("The lowest gpa is " + newGpa + " and the name of the student who got it is " + lowestStudent +"\n");
    }
    public void highestGpa() {
        int y = -1;
        int sum;

        //in the line below I made a new array to hold the values that the loop will create from teh old array
        int[] newMarks= new int[marks.length];

        //the loop will make new values to then ut in a new array that hold 5 summations of the old secondary arrays
        for (int i= 0; i <marks.length; i++) {
            y++;
            sum = 0;
            for (int j =0; j<marks[i].length; j++) {
                sum += marks[i][j];
            }
            newMarks[y] = sum;
        }
        String highestStudent = "";
        int oldGpa =newMarks[0];
        int z;
        //in this loop I can find the highest gpa of the students
        for (z=0; z< newMarks.length; z++) {
            if (newMarks[z] > oldGpa) {
                oldGpa = newMarks[z];
            }
            highestStudent= names[z];
        }
        double newGpa =oldGpa/5;
        System.out.println("The highest gpa is " + newGpa + " and the student who got it is " +highestStudent + "\n");
    }
}
```

Can you tell me why removeStudent is removing the last 2 arrays inside it and show me how to fix it, please ?

My program was done but I remembered that there could be exceptions such as two people having the same name so i started rewriteing it so it does not throw errors incase there is two people with the same names.

Comment: One problem is that by the time you are copying the marks into newMarks you have already set names to newNames, so you can't compare the names any more.

Comment: can you rewrite the method in a way that it doesn't do that ? please

Comment: @pro StackOverflow probably isn't the place to have people provide code for you - I'm not sure if this is an assignment, but it might be worth taking a look over [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Having said that - given the initial pointers provided above it might be worth you trying to implement what's been suggested, and if you struggle with that ask questions/edit this question for the bits you're finding difficult.

Comment: Set `names = newNames` after you've copied the marks.

Comment: You question seems awfully similar to this one: [hey guys i have this program that does operations on 2 arrays and one of them is a two-dimensional array but it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739399/hey-guys-i-have-this-program-that-does-operations-on-2-arrays-and-one-of-them-is)